# Accessing MS-Word object model via asp.net throw error: 80080005 Server execution failed(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005(CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE))

Tags: c#

i have developed a website that allows users convert existing word file to PDF and download it, included references to Office.interop.word, and the site works fine on my development machine. When I uploaded it to my production server the functions not working in the server, In the server also installed MS-word.
even i tried below methods

1. In the command line put DCOMCNFG
2. Component Services -> Computers -> My Computer -> DCOM Config
3. Find "Microsoft Word 97 - 2003 Document" (If it is missing check if your Word is also 64 bit (if your Windows is))
4. Right click -> Properties
5. Go To Tab Security and Edit the "Customize" radio buttons so that IIS_IUSRS could have rights for launch and access
6. Go to Tab Identity and choose "The interactive user"
7. all this fails then i have tried to tab "General" and in "Authentication Level" drop down choose "None".

still the error continue...

> Error : "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 
>   80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE))."

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

You have reached a dead end. Running Office programs inside an ASP.NET webserver is [not supported](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757):

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

I would suggest to find other ways to do what you want. There are a lot of libraries capable of reading and writing Office documents without using Office itself.